# for loop with grep not returning record by record

Tags: awk, grep, for

I have the below for loop in my shell script:

```
#!bin/ksh
touch output.dat
IFS=">>>"
i=0
for stm in `grep "cpdctl dsjob run-pipeline --project " input_file`
do
echo "the current stmt is : $stm"
done
```

In my input file **input_file** I have two records matching the pattern.
So I expected the output to be like

```
----Expected output
the current stmt is : "first line matching pattern"
the current stmt is : "second line matching pattern"

---Actual output
the current stmt is : "first line matching pattern"
"second line matching pattern"
```

`the current stmt is :`  is missing in my actual output

Can you please let me know what am I missing? I tried AWK as well but same output. I did some search but could not find any similar issues posted.

[Edit] Just now it occurred to me that it might be because of the *IFS=">>>"* line I may be having this problem. So, including my full code. I added *IFS=">>>"* as my records contained space characters and because of that for loop was returning them in separate lines.

Comment: Which grep are you using ? As when I run the exact same command as you do (with two lines matching) I get a line for each word

Comment: The code in your question can't produce the output you say it does in your question. Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input, expected output, and minimal, complete code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: If you are trying to process *lines* of output in (AT&T) ksh you should probably be using a "while" loop rather than a "for" loop - something like `while IFS= read -r line; do something with "$line"; done < <(grep ... )`

Comment: It's good you've added a more complete code example but you still haven't provided the input that produces the output you say you're seeing.

Comment: btw `IFS=">>>"` doesn't set `IFS` to the string `>>>`, it sets it to the character `>` since `IFS` is a set of characters, not a string of characters.

Comment: Since the problem was apparently caused by code not shown in the question, I am closing this as non-reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` :

```bash
awk '/cpdctl dsjob run-pipeline --project / {print "the current stmt is :", $0}' input
```

This will print each line containing `cpdctl dsjob run-pipeline --project`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble everyone. The below post helped to resolve the issue. I gave "\n" as IFS initially, but it did not work [the below link explains why]. Thanks for all your valuable input.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831429/when-setting-ifs-to-split-on-newlines-why-is-it-necessary-to-include-a-backspac][1]